# Any way to grow/shed hair?

Tags: hair

Does anybody know of a way to make hair/fur grow or shed during an animation. 
For example, if I wanted to do a transformation from a werewolf/animal/furry to a human/reptile or vice versa, is there currently any way to cause the hair system to grow or shed in patches to achieve that kind of effect, or is it currently out of Blender's reach?
Note: I am a "noob".

Comment: did you try animating the "hair length" value?

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: adding keyframes: select animation frame, hover mouse cursor over the value, press the "i" keyboard key. move to a later frame, change value, repeat. you can animate pretty much everything in blender, using keyframes....

Comment: Wait, that would make all the hair grow equally, wouldn't it... Unless one uses multiple hair systems... I assume that would be the way to do it?
 Also, is there any way of making the hairs detach and fall off, Van Helsing style?